# Encrypted strings in software

Tags: encryption, reverse-engineering, deobfuscation, ollydbg, cracking

I am new to reverse engineering.
I am using immunity debugger, x64 dbg, ollydbg.
Softwares like **Winzip** we can't able to read it's strings because it is obfuscated (encrypted).
I have watched some tutorials on YouTube, but those softwares ( power iso) strings were unencrypted.
I need to know is there any way to deobfuscate (decrypt), it's strings to reverse engineer

Comment: You could dump the memory at runtime, in many cases all the strings are deobfuscated by then.

Answer (score 2):

Obfuscation should not be confused with Encryption, semantics aside, Encryption is ***strong*** protection against capable attackers, Obfuscation is not.

With regard to your question, the theoretical approach is:

1. Identify cryptographic primitive being employed
2. Identify mode of operation, cryptographic trap-door function
3. Execute best known attack on cipher-text